# Precise mathematical version of Shannon-Nyquist sampling theorem?

Tags: fourier-analysis, information-theory

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem#Introduction), it gives the following statement for the theorem:

> If a function $x(t)$ contains no frequencies higher than B hertz, it is completely determined by giving its ordinates at a series of points spaced $\frac 1 {2B}$ seconds apart.

What is the precise mathematical version of the theorem? I.e. something like: *Let $x:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a twice differentiable function. Then if the Fourier transform .... then there is a ...*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The classical formulation of the Shannon sampling theorem, which If I recall actually predates Shannon, is as follows:

**Theorem (Shannon)**: Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f$ has 'band limit' B, i.e. $\text{supp}{\hat{f}}\subseteq[-B,B] $, then
$$f(x) = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} f\left(\frac{k}{2B}\right)\text{sinc}\left(2Bx-k\right) $$ holds in the $L^2$ sense. Here $\text{sinc}(x)$ refers the the 'normalized' version, i.e. $\frac{\sin\pi x}{\pi x}$, rather than $\frac{\sin x}{x}$. This result follows by expanding $\hat{f}$ as a Fourier series over $L^2[-B,B]$, recovering Fourier coefficients, and applying Fourier inversion. The right hand side is known
**Whittaker–Shannon interpolation formula**, and gives an explicit reconstuction for the 'signal'. Notice that $\text{sinc}(x)$ corresponds to $\text{rect}(\xi)$, a 'rectangular pulse', when taking Fourier transforms.

Now we can also explain **over/subsampling**, and **anti-aliasing** using mathematical language.

**Proposition (anti-aliasing)**: Let $f,g\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $B>0$, and further assume that $\hat{g} = \hat{f} \chi_{[-B,B]}$, then $g$ minimizes the $L^2$ distance $\int_\mathbb{R} \lvert f-h\rvert^2$ among all functions $h$ with band limit $B$.

It's clear from Shannon's theorem that even if $B$ is greater than the Nyquist frequency, the Whittaker-Shannon formula still holds, so oversampling does not hurt reconstruction of signals.For an interesting tie-in to complex analysis, there is the **Paley-Wiener theorem**, as follows:Define the **Paley-Wiener space** (modulo some factors of $2\pi$ which I may have forgotten) as
$$PW_R := \{ u :\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}\,\text{entire}\,:\,\lvert u(z)\rvert \leq C \exp(R|z|)\}$$ and suppose $u \in PW_R$ such that $f:=u|_\mathbb{R} \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, then $u\in PW_R$ iff $f$ has band limit $R$. But wait, it get's better. Define the **Bernstein space**
$$B_R = \left\{u\, \text{entire}\,:\, \sup_{t\in\mathbb{R}}e^{-R|t|}\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x+it)|^2\,dx<\infty\right\}$$
By the Phragmén–Lindelöf principle, these are actually the same space! Amazing isn't it. But you might ask, what practical use are Paley-Wiener spaces? Well, the **Paley-Wiener-Levinson theorem** provides a generalization of the above ideas to non-uniform sampling.

**Theorem (Levinson)**: Suppose $\{t_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is a sequence of sample points such that $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} |t_n-n|<\frac{1}{4}$, and $f\in B_{\pi}$, then
$$f(z) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}f(t_n) \frac{G(z)}{G'(t_n)(z-t_n)} $$
where $G(z) = (z-t_0)\prod_{n\geq 1}(1-\frac{z}{t_n})(1-\frac{z}{t_{-n}})$, with locally-uniform convergence. Note that $G(z)$ is essentially the infinite analogue of a Lagrange polynomial interpolant. Furthermore, If we have uniform spacing, and $t_0=0$, $G(z)$ is a Weierstrass product for sine, so we recover the usual Whittaker–Shannon.

Now it turns out you can (sometimes) beat the Shannon theorem, via probabilistic methods (c.f. [this paper](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/4792/1/CANieeetit06.pdf) by Emmanuel Candès, Justin Romberg and Terence Tao, and [this one](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.95.3320&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by David Donoho, for an introduction to **compressed sensing**). Results like this have been used to develop image processing techniques; this is closely related to convex optimization, linear and non-linear programming, etc...

Comment: Thank you! A few questions: What is the $n$ in $sinc$? What is $f^{\hat}$? Is the $\subset[-B,B]$ supposed to be $\subseteq$ or $\subsetneq$? By $L^1$ and $L^2$ you mean the $L^p$ spaces i.e. Lebesgue spaces?

Comment: Oops, $n$ is supposed to be $k$. $\hat{f}$ denotes the Fourier transform of $f$. The inclusion is non-strict, indeed the equality still holds for minimum sampling rates (i.e. double the Nyquist frequency). Yes, $L^1,L^2$ refer to Lebesgue spaces.

Comment: The question of @user56834 about the inclusion in the first stated Theorem of Shannon is an important one. The inclusion **must** be *non*-strict: fix $\theta \in (\pi/2, \pi/2)$ and see that sampling the function $f(t) := \cos(2\pi B t + \theta)/cos(\theta)$ at points $n/2B$  gives $f(n/2B) = \cos(n \pi + \theta)/\cos(\theta) = \cos(n \pi) = (-1)^n$. This is highly under-determined in the space of $B$-bandlimited signals. The statement of the theorem should also be updated for this reason.

Comment: Regarding sampling below the $2B$ rate as discussed in the last paragraph: it's less to do with the *methods* involved and more to do with additional assumptions on the *signals*. One can apply minimization methods, even deterministically, to fully reconstruct signals by from sampling well below the $2B$ rate, *if* one additionally assumes the signals are in some sense sparse, among other things.

Comment: great answer, @lc2r43! could you point us to some references where we can find more details?